# How can I call Kibana using zuul

Tags: docker-compose, kibana, microservices, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I have multiple services say **Node-Service** running on docker. Along with that, I have [EFK Stack](https://docs.fluentd.org/v0.12/articles/docker-logging-efk-compose) also running as a Docker Container.

The Node-Services are getting register on [Eureka](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka) and getting called from the external network using [Api-Gateway (Zuul)](https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-communication-zuul-api-gateway-1).

My question is

- How can I call Kibana (Service among EFK) using zuul routes?
- Is it possible to register **Kibana** on **Eureka** ??

Here Is my docker-compose to run **EFK**

```
version: '2'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch
    expose:
      - 9200
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"


  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd/conf:/fluentd/etc
    links:
      - "elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "24224:24224"
      - "24224:24224/udp"


  kibana:
    image: kibana
    links:
      - "elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "9201:5601"
```

Below is the snippt for docker-ps

[image]

Please Suggest the solution